# Google Voice Autodialer -- ie:, any way to send a phone number to Google Voice (or the google-chat plugin) in order to initiate a call?

Tags: html, voip, google-voice

This is a dumb sounding question, but I've tried to find an answer digging through FAQs and forums, and came up short.

Just like you can use `tel:` in hyperlinks for mobile browsers, you can set a link to start a call with Skype's software with:

```
<a href="skype:15555555">Call This Number</a>
```

Is there any way to do anything similar with Google Voice? Or, as of recent, Gmail? Or the Google/voice/chat/whatever plugin? It seems they're really trying to solder a lot of their projects together, and I understand there's nothing like a desktop software package, until/unless they decide to overhaul their '[Google Talk](http://www.google.com/talk/)' to support VoIP calling.

But, surely, with all of this stuff going live, there's a way to just link a phone number manually. No little API? Can't send POST/GET somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Simulating the HTTP POST requests needed to initate Google Voice calls and SMS is pretty easy and there are a few tools/utilities around that do it. A couple of C# classes I wrote to do exactly that job are [GoogleVoiceCall](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54573#476744) and [GoogleVoiceSMS](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54573#1059695).

To do the equivalent from a HTML page the best bet would be to use javascript/jquery. The sample C# classes should show be easy enough to follow as to the mechanism and which parameters need to be sent in the POST requests.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an API for python:
http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/

Java: http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

C#/.NET: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/

I think there's an API in Ruby also.  You basically need to login to your google voice and extract the "API KEY", then use the API.